# помогите с ajax запросом

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть функция, которая, по сути, только меняет `background` по клику на элемент.

Каким образом можно добавить ajax функцию, которая будет просто каким-нибудь console.log выводить информацию об успешном или не успешном запросе, и делать тоже самое, что и функция вышеуказанная, при тех же кликах на блоки?

js

```
var activeFavoriteCompare = function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains("active")){
        e.target.classList.remove("active");
    } else{
        e.target.classList.add("active");
    }
};

if(block_favorite){
    for(var i = 0, len = block_favorite.length; i < len; i++){
        eventsObj.addEvent(block_favorite[i], "click",  activeFavoriteCompare, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть, если я правильно понял, Вам нужно вести лог этой операции на клиенте?

Comment: именно так бы и хотел

Answer (score 1):

решил таким образом

```
(function(){         

            var targetElement = document.getElementsByClassName('price_decrease '),
                xml = eventsObj.getXmlHttp(),
                send,
                el;
            var lower = function(e) {
                 for ( var i=0;i<targetElement.length;i++){
                     if ( e.target == targetElement[i]) {               
                        el = targetElement[i];                   
                     } else {
                        return false; 
                     } 
                }                                
                if (el.classList.contains('active')) {                  
                    send = 0;                                  
                } else {
                    send = 1;                   
                }                
                xml.open("POST", "ссылка на пхп файл", true);
                xml.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xml.send("el_send="+encodeURIComponent(send));
                xml.onreadystatechange = function(){
                    if(xml.readyState === 4){
                        if(xml.status === 200){
                            if(xml.responseText !== ""){
                                if(xml.responseText === "ok"){

                                    if(send === 0){
                                        console.log('inactive');
                                        el.classList.remove('active');                                            

                                     }
                                    else if(send === 1){
                                        console.log('active')
                                        el.classList.add('active');

                                    }                                    
                                }
                                else if(xml.responseText === "no"){
                                   console.log("try again later");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                };                
            }
            for(var i = 0; i < Blocks.length; i++){
            eventsObj.addEvent(Blocks[i], "click",  lower, false);
            };

})();
```

где `Blocks` элемент по которому кликаем

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно вести лог данной операции на клиенте, можно записывать нужные данные в файл либо с помощью *ActiveX* (не кроссплатформенно и  не кроссбраузерно) либо использовать возможности *HTML5* (File API и т.д.), но они пока тоже поддерживаются не везде."Обычный" *JavaScript* не умеет работать с файловой системой.

Как вариант, ещё можно предложить вести такой лог на сервере, а на клиенте реализовать его просмотр.

Comment: как говорится , я не волшебник, а данные об ответе в принципе не нужно записывать , просто ок или не ок если запрос успешный/не успешный

Comment: Дело в том, что при записи Вам придётся работать с файловой системой. Поэтому, нет никакой разницы, что писать в лог. Ситуация от этого никоим образом не изменится.

Comment: просто не понятна необходимость работы с файловой системой

Comment: Необходимость работы с файловой системой объясняется тем, что Вы собираетесь писать данные в лог, а лог это, как правило, файл. На сервере ещё доступна возможность писать лог в БД.

Comment: для начала хотелось бы на простом примере сделать отладку, а потом думать про запись данных логов куда либо

Comment: Если цель просто отладка, то чем Вас не устраивает обычная консоль браузера? К слову, для некоторых браузеров есть даже специальные плагины для отладки...

Comment: хотелось просто разобраться с ajax в данном примере

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34661/discussion-between-streletz-and-dirk).